# "code": 0, "msg": "Service unavailable from a restricted location according to 'b

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

When I make requst in Google sheets to get options data from Binance by API-request I'm always getting the same message with an error. My code:

```
function DownLoad_options_OI(BaceAsset) {
  url='https://eapi.binance.com/eapi/v1/openInterest?underlyingAsset=BaceAsset;expiration=230113';
  options = {muteHttpExceptions: true};
  var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)
  return response.getContentText()
}
```

The Execution log in Google Apps Script shows that all is OK. But when I transfer any value to function DownLoad_options_OI (BTC or ETH) I'm always getting the same message with error:

"code": 0,
"msg": "Service unavailable from a restricted location according to 'b. Eligibility' in https://www.binance.com/en/terms. Please contact customer service if you believe you received this message in error."

But the same request in browser is working:
https://eapi.binance.com/eapi/v1/openInterest?underlyingAsset=BTC;expiration=230113

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi and welcome. "For the purposes hereof, “Restricted Location” shall include the United States, Malaysia, Ontario (Canada), and such other locations as designated by Binance Operators from time to time as a “Restricted Location” for the purposes hereof; " Would you please advise, where in the world are you located, or (at least) where in the world does Binance "think" that your computer/browser are located?

Comment: I'm in Ukraine at the moment

Comment: OK, well let's consider two possibilities. 1) Sheets is a cloud-based app and it is possible that the server running your spreadsheet/function is located in the USA. Since binance.com regards the USA as a "Restricted Location", it is not surprising that your function would generate a "Service unavailable from a restricted location" message. 2) You are in the Ukraine. When your browser makes a request, the binance.com server determines that the request has come from the Ukraine (which is NOT a restricted location), so the request is satisfied.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
info = Client(tld='us').get_historical_klines(symbol, timeframe, starting_date)
```